# numpy , applying function over list optimization

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have this two code that are doing the same but for different data structs

```
res = np.array([np.array([2.0, 4.0, 6.0]), np.array([8.0, 10.0, 12.0])], dtype=np.int)
%timeit np.sum(res, axis=1)
4.08 µs ± 728 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
list_obj_array = np.ndarray((2,), dtype=np.object)
list_obj_array[0] = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
list_obj_array[1] = [8.0, 10.0, 12.0]

v_func = np.vectorize(np.sum, otypes=[np.int])
%timeit v_func(list_obj_array)
20.6 µs ± 486 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

the second one is 5 times slower , is there a better way to optimize this?

```
@nb.jit()
def nb_np_sum(arry_list):
   return [np.sum(row) for row in arry_list]

%timeit nb_np_sum(list_obj_array)
30.8 µs ± 5.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
@nb.jit()
def nb_sum(arry_list):
    return [sum(row) for row in arry_list]

%timeit nb_sum(list_obj_array)
13.6 µs ± 669 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Best so far (thanks @hpaulj)

```
%timeit [sum(l) for l in list_obj_array]
850 ns ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```
@nb.njit()
def nb_sum(arry_list):
    return [sum(row) for row in arry_list]


TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'sum': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

File "<ipython-input-54-3bb48c5273bb>", line 3:
def nb_sum(arry_list):
        return [sum(row) for row in arry_list]
```

for longer array

```
list_obj_array = np.ndarray((n,), dtype=np.object)
for i in range(n):
    list_obj_array[i] = list(range(7))
```

the `vectorized` version come closer to the best option (list Comprehension)

```
%timeit [sum(l) for l in list_obj_array]
23.4 µs ± 4.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
 %timeit v_func(list_obj_array)
29.6 µs ± 4.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

numba still is slower

```
%timeit nb_sum(list_obj_array)
74.4 µs ± 6.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Numpy introduces a pretty big latency for small arrays. If you do a lot of computation on such a small arrays, then Numpy is probably not the right tool. However, please note that Numba could be used to speed up such operations if you do that in batch (probably much faster than using pure-Python functions/data-types due to the slow interpreter).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, 10xs 4 the explanation that clear some thing 

i did tried numba see above the results wasn't faster

Comment: Why are you even working with `numpy` arrays with python lists in them? Just use regular lists

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , the above is just a toy code , my system work with numpy all over , in some cases however it should process list

Comment: Numba is not faster because it did not succeed to compile the function (see `Failed in nopython mode pipeline`) mainly because the function work on pure-Python objects. Such objects are inherently slow. Since Numba failed to compile the code, the benchmarked functions is just a pure-Python function. You need to work on statically-typed native objects such as Numpy array with natively-typed items if you want to reach high-performance (or possibly lists with natively-typed items though they are not so fast in Numba). Besides, note the type of the first array items is `np.float64`, not `np.int`.

Comment: 10xs @JérômeRichard, yes i see that the numba couldn't optimized the code 
but this is the input i get, it is a list. 
tought that numba is smart enough to handle list of float 
10xs for the type comment . u r right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `otypes` you read enough of the `vectorize` docs to know that it is not a performance tool.

```
In [430]: timeit v_func(list_obj_array)
38.3 µs ± 894 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

A list comprehension is faster:

```
In [431]: timeit [sum(l) for l in list_obj_array]
2.08 µs ± 62.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Even better if you start with a list of list instead on of an object dtype array:

```
In [432]: alist = list_obj_array.tolist()
In [433]: timeit [sum(l) for l in alist]
542 ns ± 11.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

### edit

`np.frompyfunc` is faster than `np.vectorize`, especially when working with object dtype arrays:

```
In [459]: np.frompyfunc(sum,1,1)(list_obj_array)
Out[459]: array([12.0, 30.0], dtype=object)
In [460]: timeit np.frompyfunc(sum,1,1)(list_obj_array)
2.22 µs ± 16.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As I've seen elsewhere `frompyfunc` is competitive with the list comprehension.

Interestingly, using `np.sum` instead of `sum` slows it down.  I think that's because `np.sum` applied to lists has the overhead of converting the lists to arrays.  `sum` applied to lists of numbers is pretty good, using python's own compiled code.

```
In [461]: timeit np.frompyfunc(np.sum,1,1)(list_obj_array)
30.3 µs ± 165 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So let's try `sum` in your vectorize:

```
In [462]: v_func = np.vectorize(sum, otypes=[int])
In [463]: timeit v_func(list_obj_array)
8.7 µs ± 331 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Much better.

Comment: very nice. yes i read that vectorize is not a performance tool
but i did expect that numpy would be faster. 
10xs

Comment: The first case is "pure" numpy, using compiled `sum` on a multidimensional array.  The second is an object dtype array, which is basically a list.  It has to iterate at list speeds through the elements of the array.  Python iteration on arrays is slower than the same iteration on lists.

Comment: so what makes it so fast when it use list comprehension
couldn't numpy do the same ?

Comment: 10xs @hpaulj, so pure python come first , then the vectorize and as array become bigger 
the vectorized come closer, but still python wins!

Comment: @sami `np.vectorize` is essentially a naive, Python loop.

Comment: @hpaulj, also replace the np.sum with python sum on the np.frompyfunc
like this
np.frompyfunc(np.sum,1,1)(list_obj_array)
it will make it faster

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes i know np.vectorize and also is not meant as a performance tool , but yet it is doing the work. it is the second best result and it is close to the best as array become bigger